# Is there a way to decrypt Salt Hashing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, bcrypt

Let's say I have this Backend Code which Hashes the password of the user

```js
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
```

And for the auth, I just use the Bcrypt Compare function

```js
const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
```

It works. But let's say I want to know the Password as well. Is there a `bcrypt` function for that? Because as far as I know, the only thing it can do is compare the Passwords.

Comment: Hashes are *by design* not reversible. And bcrypy is further *by design* even harder to find hashes for in order to prevent precomputing a table of many passwords to check against the hash. What you're trying to do is not what you should be doing for these two reasons and more.

Comment: can i ask why you want to decrypt it?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of password hashing is making an irreversible action so that anyone else including you cannot reverse the process and get the password. So answer is you can't know. Once it has been hashed there is no going back.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing (either it is MD5 salt hashing, SHA256/SHA512 or salt hashing) is a one way function,you cannot decrypt it, instead you can use RSA encryption with Diffie-Hellman key exchange technique.

[Bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) library is for Hashing passwords, if you want to retrieve back passwords, you can't do with it.

Instead use [RSA](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa) with Diffie-Hellman key exchange technique to securely share keys.

Comment: So Bcrypt is a no-go?

Comment: Yes, if you want to encrypt a message you can use crypto-js library.
Here you will find more information about [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

Comment: Checkout [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuyzuNBFWxQ&t=451s) for general understanding and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAZJOPQQr1M) for deffie hellman key exchange algorithm.